# Indentation 4 spaces is not working in scalafmt.config in VS Code

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, scalafmt, scala-metals

I am trying to setup ***scalafmt.config***, such that it formats my code. All the features I am using -- such as `align.preset = more`, `align.openParenDefnSite = false` etc. -- seem to work perfectly. However, I have an issue with indentation. I want to set it to 4, not 2 as it is at the moment. So, I tried using the following:

```
continuationIndent.callSite = 4
continuationIndent.defnSite = 4
continuationIndent.ctorSite = 4
```

And no success. I expected my whole code to indent by 4, but it is still at indent 2.

I am using Visual Studio Code with Metals as my plugin. Also, I have ***scalafmt*** installed locally on my laptop version 2.5.0.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to have 4 spaces everywhere. There's even an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/scalameta/scalafmt/issues/1493. Since 2 spaces is a Scala standard, they seem to have decided not to support it

Comment: @user thanks for your reply! Guess this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring `indent.main = 4` works fine for me

```
# .scalafmt.conf
version = "3.5.3"
runner.dialect = scala212
indent.main = 4
```